# mongorestore to restore the dump is failing

Tags: mongodb

When I run below command , I'm getting the output as shown, How to fix this?

C:\Users\tadoori\Downloads\dump\m101>**mongorestore dump**

**2016-10-21T13:54:09.883-0600    Failed: mongorestore target 'dump' invalid: GetFileAttributesEx dump: The system cannot find the file specified.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The argument you pass to mongodump is the dump path

As it seems you are already on the dump folder you can also specify the absolute path.

```
mongorestore C:\Users\tadoori\Downloads\dump
```

This will restore all dump folder contents (if the files are valid)

Comment: C:\Users\tadoori\Downloads\dump>mongorestore
2016-10-21T14:05:53.655-0600    using default 'dump' directory
2016-10-21T14:05:53.705-0600    see mongorestore --help for usage information
2016-10-21T14:05:53.729-0600    Failed: mongorestore target 'dump' invalid: GetFileAttributesEx dump: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Tried with mongorestore getting output as in above comment

Comment: @user6238728 I've edited my answer, you can use the absolute path to make sure you pass in the dump folder

Comment: bson and json files are available in this path      C:\Users\tadoori\Downloads\dump\m101           .....

Comment: 2016-10-21T14:10:58.684-0600    don't know what to do with file "C:\Users\tadoori\Downloads\dump\m101\funnynumbers.bson",skippin
2016-10-21T14:10:58.686-0600    don't know what to do with file "C:\Users\tadoori\Downloads\dump\m101\funnynumbers.metadata.json", skipping...
2016-10-21T14:10:58.692-0600    done
Im getting something like this ...is it fine?

Comment: the dump folder should have all the databases. m101 should be one of them, that's because it's in a subfolder. Using the dump folder should restore all the subfolders databases

Comment: oh ok thanks.... mongorestore C:\Users\tadoori\Downloads\dump  .....  this worked

Comment: Check if the data you want is in the database, if so, there is no problem